# How to find text is highlighted or not in mainframe using vba

Tags: vba, screen-scraping, mainframe

I have one transaction which is purchase.. the same tramsaction is getting reversed then this transaction will be highlighted..

I need to verify that the transaction is highlighted or not.

Is there any way using vba??

Comment: Where are you seeing this transaction highlighted? In a mainframe tool like CICS?

Comment: CICS ISO summary screen

Comment: Which 3270 emulator are you using?

Comment: Rocket bluezone

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about using VBA to screen scrape a 3270 CICS interface to determine if a particular field is highlighted.

This depends on the capabilities of your 3270 emulator, which you indicate is Rocket BlueZone.

According to the [FAQ for the product](https://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-bluezonepassport-terminal-emulator/rocket-bluezone-terminal-emulation-faq), it does support screen scraping and has both its own API and various HLLAPI interfaces.

You're going to have to read your documentation to discover if you can do what you want (determine if a particular field is highlighted) the way you want to do it (with VBA).